# Oracle date parameters

Tags: oracle10g

I have a query that creates for me exactly what I want but if I start to use parameters it says me not all variables bound. How can I achieve to query between two dates in following select statement?

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards

```
select case vp.player_type
         when 'L' then
          lpm.last_name
         when 'C' then
          cpm.last_name
       end as last_name,
       case vp.player_type
         when 'L' then
          lpm.first_name
         when 'C' then
          cpm.first_name
       end as first_name,
       lag(ch.next_date) over(partition by ch.virtual_customer_id order by ch.end_date) as scheduled_date,
       ch.date_entered as start_com_date,
       ch.end_date as end_com_date,
       round(ch.date_entered - lag(ch.next_date)
             over(partition by ch.virtual_customer_id order by ch.end_date)) as date_dif,
       case
         when ch.date_entered - lag(ch.next_date)
          over(partition by ch.virtual_customer_id order by ch.end_date) > 45 then
          'overdue'
         else
          null
       end as overdue,
            tt.tot_actualloss as lg_loss,
            stt.tot_actualloss as slot_loss,
       ch.response,
       to_char(ch.notes) as notes,
       casinocrm.main.getUserName(ch.user_id) as entered_by,
       ch.next_date as next_com_date,
       ch.id as communication_id,
       ch.virtual_customer_id
  from casinocrm.communication_history ch
  join casinocrm.virtual_player vp
    on vp.id = ch.virtual_customer_id
  left join logismos.player_master lpm
    on lpm.link_id = vp.player_id
   and vp.player_type = 'L'
  left join casinocrm.potential_player_master cpm
    on cpm.link_id = vp.player_id
   and vp.player_type = 'C'
left join logismos.trak_totals tt
    on tt.memb_linkid = lpm.link_id
left join logismos.trak_totals_sl stt
    on stt.memb_linkid = lpm.link_id
 where ch.date_entered between TO_DATE(:startdate,'DD/MM/YYY' ) and TO_DATE(:enddate,'DD/MM/YYY' )
```

Comment: How are you executing the query.  It looks like you are trying to define bind variables which generally indicates that you are using some sort of client API (something like a Java application using JDBC).  The error seems to imply that you are not using whatever calls that API provides to define values for those bind variables before executing your statement.  Explaining how to do that, however, will require knowing what client API we're talking about.

Comment: I am not using any ide or client API right now. I am planing to use c# but before that I am trying to get correct results from query. Just debugging query inside navicat.

Comment: Navicat is some sort of GUI?  Does Navicat prompt you for values for anything that starts with a colon?  That would be a GUI-specific function that would require it to pre-process the SQL statement before sending it to the database.  It's entirely possible that it does, I'm not an expert with this particular tool.  Do you actually need to be prompted for values, though?  If you're just trying to validate results, is there a reason that you don't just use literal values?

Comment: No it's not prompt any values. If I change startdate and andenddate with dates query is working.

Comment: If the query is working when you're using literals, then either you should continue using literals or you'd need a Navicat expert to tell you whether it can pre-process a statement to prompt for bind variables and the Navicat-specific syntax to cause that preprocessing and prompting to take place.  Unfortunately, that expert is not me.

Comment: Sorry Justin. How about creating procedure?

Comment: A procedure to do what?  You could create a procedure that took two IN parameters of type `DATE` and had an `OUT` parameter of type `SYS_REFCURSOR` and use that to return a ref cursor (though, at that point, it would make more sense to use a function than a procedure).  But it's not clear what problem that is solving or whether your GUI knows how to call that procedure and how to fetch the data from the ref cursor that is returned to display it to you in a useful manner.